# Simple Past vs Present Perfect

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

It's really confusing to choose the correct tense between simple past and present perfect.

Let's assume one situation:

Every student has to bring his/her own name tag to the class, but today I forgot to bring it. If a professor notices that I'm not with the name tag now, she would ask me:

- 'Don't you have your name tag?'

Then I would say:

- 'Yes. I have the name tag but I forgot to bring it', right?

But is it okay for me to say:

- 'Yes. I have the name tag but I didn't bring it', or
- 'Yes. I have the name tag but I haven't brought it.'

Which one is correct between 'I didn't bring it' and 'I haven't brought it'?
(So confusing to pick up the right tense.)

Comment: It's more helpful if you asked for the difference between _"forgot to bring"_ and _"have forgotten to bring"_, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in the scenario you presented, you could use both of them, and it would be correct.

However, in some other scenarios, they can have slightly different connotations. Lets take this example:

**Firstly with the past simple**

> A. We are going to have to buy a new sofa, thanks to your reckless actions.
>
> B. Mum, I didn't break the sofa!

This could suggest that the action has happened in the past. In this scenario, it suggests that B denies breaking the sofa.

**With perfect present**

> A. We are going to have to buy a new sofa...
>
> B. Mum, I haven't broken the sofa!

Although this could mean the same thing as the first example, a connotation could be that *B thinks that the sofa is not broken*.

So yes, usually both versions can be interchangeable, but they can have slightly different meanings. So in response to your question, I think this is the best option:

> Yes, I have the name tag but I forgot to bring it.

because it is an action that has happened in the past, and you are apologising for it, but...

**you can use them both**.